# iphone: Memory Leak involving NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, memory-leaks

I have a little piece of code here that updates an `ALAssetGroup` (photo album) if a user makes a change to their photo library:

```
- (void) ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification
{
    [[self activityIndicator] startAnimating]; 

    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    [[self library] enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop)
    {
        if (group != nil)
        {
            NSString *newAlbumID = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [group valueForProperty: ALAssetsGroupPropertyPersistentID]]; 

            if ([newAlbumID isEqualToString: self.albumID])
            {
                self.album = group;
                [self loadPhotos];
                [newAlbumID release];
                return;
            }

            [newAlbumID release];
        }

    }
    failureBlock:^(NSError *error) 
    {
    }];

    [pool release];

}
```

It works, but only for so long before I get a "signalbrt" and a corresponding "`-[UIButtonContent isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`" to go along with it (sometimes `UIButtonContent` will be `NSArray` instead). I also enabled zombies and got messages like "`*** -[CFString release]: message sent to deallocated instance" and "*** -[CFString class]: message sent to deallocated instance`". I've tried allocating the string in a bunch of different ways, none which have worked correctly. Does anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
        NSString *newAlbumID = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [group valueForProperty: ALAssetsGroupPropertyPersistentID] autorelease];
```

and remove the other releases to this object.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be to suspect that `self.albumID` or `self.album` are declared as `assign` rather than `retain` or `copy`, or that something is wrong in `loadPhotos`.  Check the declarations for these properties and temporarily remove the `loadPhotos` call.  Does it still crash?

The two releases for the string you allocate are kosher, but the way that code is organised makes it difficult to reason about.  You should refactor it so the string is either autoreleased or released once.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is most likely related to the 'group' variable and or the 'valueForProperty' call on this group variable.  This is possibly being released underneath you somewhere.  Thus when you are initialising your 'newAlbumId' from a property on the 'group' variable you are getting assigned a pointer to random memory (since the group object or  has been released), which is ending up being a pointer to a 'UIButtonContent' or sometimes and 'NSArray'.  Doing the 'isEqualToString' thus gets the error that is thrown.  Similarly thats why you are getting warnings with zombies enabled.

When you have NSZombies enabled are you getting any warnings in relation to accessing the group variable?

Also how is the object referenced by the group variable memory managed - are you alloc/initing and and assigning it directly to an iVar in the containing object (rather than as a property via a property accessor)? If so make sure you are not 'releasing' it after this alloc, as since it is not a property it is not getting retained on the iVar assignment -  you only need to just release it in your dealloc method (or set it up as a property instead).

Just looking at the ALAssetsGroup class you are most likely initialising the group iVar by assigning the result of convenience method call - if so this convenience method is autoreleasing the group object it returns, so you need to make sure you 'retain' the value when you assign it to your group variable in the containing object.  (or probably simpler, make group a retain property on your containing object, and assign via the property accessor method).